# Which state describes carrier transport through channel? A mixed state or a pure state?

Tags: quantum-state, density-matrix

A pure quantum state is a state which can be described by a single ket vector. A mixed quantum state is a statistical ensemble of pure states. When carriers transport from source to drain in a Field Effect Transistor, which state could describe it?
A pure state or a mixed state?

Comment: The "source to drain" terminology is specific to Field Effect Transistors and not general semiconductors. You might also want to clarify that by "channel" you're referring to channels in transistors. And in general, it's always mixed states.

Comment: Thanks for your correction! But why is it mixed states generally?

Comment: Mixed states are the most general, so they can also describe pure states. If you want to describe $|0\rangle$, you could also write it as $|0\rangle \langle 0 |$ in density matrix form.